# go panic - No data received - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: http, session, go, struct, rethinkdb

I'm using `gorethink` driver, I write a query function like this in model

```
func GetQuotesByUser(idUser string) []Quote{
    ids:=GetQuoteIdsByUser(idUser)
    if (len(ids)>0){
        result,err:=r.Table("quote").GetAll(ids...).Run(config.Connection())
        defer result.Close()

        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
            return []Quote{}
        }
        var quotes []Quote
        err=result.All(&quotes)
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
            return []Quote{}
        }
        fmt.Println(quotes)
        return quotes
    } else{
        return []Quote{}
    }
}
```

I write a route handler that calls the above function

```
import (
    "corate/util"
    "corate/model"
    "github.com/fatih/structs"
    "net/http"
)

func DashboardHandler(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    files:=[]string{"base","dashboard"}
    session,_:=util.GlobalSessions.SessionStart(w,r)
    defer session.SessionRelease(w)
    quotes:=model.GetQuotesByUser("ca8a2e14-f65b-43b1-b655-97d7c29190ec")
    q:=structs.Map(quotes)
    util.RenderTemplate(w,q,files...)
}
```

This is `main` function

```
func main(){

    // Setup database

    config.Setupdb()

    // Initialize session manager

    util.InitSessionManager()

    // Serve static folder

    http.Handle("/public/",http.StripPrefix("/public/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))

    // Setup routers and middlewares

    http.HandleFunc("/",route.IndexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/login",route.GoogleLoginHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/auth/google",route.GoogleCallbackHandler)

    http.Handle("/dashboard",negroni.New(
        negroni.HandlerFunc(route.IsAuthenticated),
        negroni.Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(route.DashboardHandler)),
    ))

    // Start listening

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000",nil)
}
```

I use `astaxie/beego/session` library to manage sessions for this server

```
import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/session"
)

var (
    GlobalSessions *session.Manager
)

func InitSessionManager() {
    GlobalSessions, _ = session.NewManager("memory", `{"cookieName":"gosessionid","gclifetime":3600}`)
    go GlobalSessions.GC()
}
```

When I start the server, and login and request to `dashboard` path, `DashboardHandler` is processed,`GetQuotesByUser` is called, and it works, it works, it does print out true results of query. But in browser, the browser throws error:

No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The console logs some errors as well

```
http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:51229: not struct
goroutine 84 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc82015fc00)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
panic(0x7f58e0, 0xc8204489f0)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:426 +0x4e9
github.com/fatih/structs.strctVal(0x7de700, 0xc82045a340, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/fatih/structs/structs.go:426 +0x136
github.com/fatih/structs.New(0x7de700, 0xc82045a340, 0x0)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/fatih/structs/structs.go:30 +0x2f
github.com/fatih/structs.Map(0x7de700, 0xc82045a340, 0xc82045a340)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/fatih/structs/structs.go:435 +0x2b
corate/route.DashboardHandler(0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/corate/route/user.go:19 +0x190
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa47820, 0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.Wrap.func1(0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460, 0xc8203f0a60)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:41 +0x50
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc82012ace0, 0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460, 0xc8203f0a60)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:24 +0x44
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.middleware.ServeHTTP(0x7fe2c2e6ade0, 0xc82012ace0, 0xc82012ad40, 0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:33 +0xaa
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.(middleware).ServeHTTP-fm(0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:33 +0x53
corate/route.IsAuthenticated(0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460, 0xc8203f0a00)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/corate/route/isAuthenticated.go:14 +0x174
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa47840, 0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460, 0xc8203f0a00)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:24 +0x44
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.middleware.ServeHTTP(0x7fe2c2e6ade0, 0xa47840, 0xc82012ad20, 0x7fe2c2e6dfc8, 0xc8202d49c0, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:33 +0xaa
github.com/codegangsta/negroni.(*Negroni).ServeHTTP(0xc8200cfe90, 0x7fe2c2e6af70, 0xc820154680, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/Workspace/Go/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni/negroni.go:73 +0x122
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc820013740, 0x7fe2c2e6af70, 0xc820154680, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x17d
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82000e380, 0x7fe2c2e6af70, 0xc820154680, 0xc820372460)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc82015fc00)
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /home/kuro/.gvm/gos/go1.6/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
```

Why does it happen? Then I notice that if I don't utilize `fatih/structs` library, nothing will go wrong. But I want to use that library, it will help me much. I want to know reason of this strange behavior and how to fix it while still using `fatih/structs` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetQuotesByUser` returns a slice, not a struct.  So you can't pass it directly to `structs.Map`.  You'll have to iterate the slice and convert each element to a map individually.

```
quotes := model.GetQuotesByUser("ca8a2e14-f65b-43b1-b655-97d7c29190ec")

qs := []map[string]interface{}{}
for _, q := range quotes {
    qs = append(qs, structs.Map(q))
}

util.RenderTemplate(w,qs,files...)
```

Should get you close to what you're after.

Comment: @necroface glad I could help :)